# Unable to convert perl script to exe using Perl2Exe

Tags: par, packer, perl2exe

I explored Perl2Exe, PAR, PAR::Packer to convert perl script to a exe. I am unable to convert via either of the options below, Kindly can you let know what needs to be done.

1) Downloaded perl2exe (p2x-11.00-Win and p2x-16.00-Win) to convert the perl script, getting below error. I am using windows 7, 32 bit.

"Invalid Platform Win64-5.20.2" - *5.20.2 is the ActivePerl version i am using.*

2) I am unable to install PAR and PAR::Packer from command prompt, it throws error while unpacking the .tgz files, saying - *can't extract files from C:\Users........*

Comment: Any idea on this experts, appreciate your inputs.